# I can't find a sqlsrv code to execute multiple SQL queries,on php, that afect each other

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Anyone can help me execute this 3 queries on php?

```
declare @result varchar(24);
 exec usp_UserLogin @aUser = '$_POST[user]', @aPassword = '$_POST[pass]', @aToken = @result out; 
select @result as token;
```

i need them to run one after each other, because as you can see, they need each other to work properly.

TY
Nuno Santos

Comment: I forgot to mention that i've tried sqlsrv_query(connection,query1;query2;query3;), and i've tried 3x sqlsrv as well..but nothing work as expected.

Comment: i mean 3xsqlsrv_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute one single query that contains those three lines, otherwise you get an error like undefined parameter. Think as you want to execute each of queries on separate SSMS query window.

Your query will be executed step by step.

```
$tsql= "declare @result varchar(24);
        exec usp_UserLogin @aUser = ?, @aPassword = ?, @aToken = @result out; 
        select @result as token;";

$params = array($_POST[user], $_POST[pass]);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $params);
```

If you want to check result of each step(seems unnecessary for this query), you should use transactions like `BEGIN TRAN`, `COMMIT TRAN`

Reference: [sqlsrv_query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @alalp. It seems like another way to do it (probably better than just separate all queries with spaces like i did xD), and because of that, i'l mark it as answer.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem:
i was putting the queries on sqlsrv separated by ";" or "," or "/n", but it was simpler than i thought! I just put them one after each other, separated by space, like this:

```
$rslt_query=sqlsrv_query($conn,"declare @result varchar(24) exec 
usp_UserLogin @aUser = '$_POST[user]', @aPassword = '$_POST[pass]', 
@aToken= @result out select @result as token ");
```

then i just fetch and grab the token for $_SESSION variable:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rslt_query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{$_SESSION['token']=$row['token'];}
```